# What is correct form of "to be thought ..."?

Tags: idioms, formality, word-form

Have a question "They are thought ... a house in London"

1. have
2. to have
3. had
4. they had

I think the answer is 2. Is correct? Why if not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are thought to have a house in London; People think they have a house in London.